# Wordspress add <p> into my javascripts

Tags: shortcode, characters

I use a slider called *revoslider* and use it via shortcode.

When i use the shortcode **and do not use visual editor for insert** and save, the slider does not work because WordPress adds `<p>` into javascript like this :

```
<p>         <script type="text/javascript"></p>
<p>             var tpj=jQuery;</p>
<p>                                 tpj.noConflict();</p>
<p>             var revapi1;</p>
<p>             tpj(document).ready(function() {</p>
<p>             if (tpj.fn.cssOriginal != undefined)
                    tpj.fn.css = tpj.fn.cssOriginal;</p>
<p>             if(tpj('#rev_slider_1_1').revolution == undefined)
                    revslider_showDoubleJqueryError('#rev_slider_1_1');
                else
                   revapi1 = tpj('#rev_slider_1_1').show().revolution(
                    {
                        delay:9000,
                        startwidth:960,
                        startheight:350,
                        hideThumbs:200,</p>
<p>                     thumbWidth:100,
                        thumbHeight:50,
                        thumbAmount:2,</p>
<p>                     navigationType:"bullet",
                        navigationArrows:"solo",
                        navigationStyle:"round",</p>
<p>                     touchenabled:"on",
                        onHoverStop:"on",</p>
<p>                     navigationHAlign:"center",
                        navigationVAlign:"bottom",
                        navigationHOffset:0,
                        navigationVOffset:20,</p>
<p>                     soloArrowLeftHalign:"left",
                        soloArrowLeftValign:"center",
                        soloArrowLeftHOffset:20,
                        soloArrowLeftVOffset:0,</p>
<p>                     soloArrowRightHalign:"right",
                        soloArrowRightValign:"center",
                        soloArrowRightHOffset:20,
                        soloArrowRightVOffset:0,</p>
<p>                     shadow:2,
                        fullWidth:"off",</p>
<p>                     stopLoop:"off",
                        stopAfterLoops:-1,
                        stopAtSlide:-1,</p>
<p>                     shuffle:"off",</p>
<p>                     hideSliderAtLimit:0,
                        hideCaptionAtLimit:0,
                        hideAllCaptionAtLilmit:0,
                        startWithSlide:0    
                    });</p>
<p>             }); //ready</p>
<p>         </script></p>
```

Because of this, the code does not work and I don´t understand why WordPress adds these `<p>` for each line - it´s ridicoulus.

I tried `add_filter`  for content but it also does not work.

Answer (score 7):

You have to either

1) take all the whitespace out of the script so WordPress does not add `<p>` tags and then the JS will work, or

2) disable `autop` in the post editor for all posts/pages
(see http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop ) so WP doesn't add paragraph breaks, or

3) do the following, which leaves `autop` enabled globally, but lets you disable it with  and  tags in individual posts and pages.

**Add the function below to functions.php and use the two tags**

`<!-- noformat on -->` and `<!-- noformat off -->`

**in your page/post editor, i.e.**

```
    text will be rendered *with* autop

    <!-- noformat on -->

    text will be rendered *without* autop

    <!-- noformat off -->

    text will be rendered *with* autop
```

Content outside of the two format tags will have autop enabled, as noted.

**Add to functions.php of the theme:**

```
// <!-- noformat on --> and <!-- noformat off --> functions

function newautop($text)
{
    $newtext = "";
    $pos = 0;

    $tags = array('<!-- noformat on -->', '<!-- noformat off -->');
    $status = 0;

    while (!(($newpos = strpos($text, $tags[$status], $pos)) === FALSE))
    {
        $sub = substr($text, $pos, $newpos-$pos);

        if ($status)
            $newtext .= $sub;
        else
            $newtext .= convert_chars(wptexturize(wpautop($sub)));      //Apply both functions (faster)

        $pos = $newpos+strlen($tags[$status]);

        $status = $status?0:1;
    }

    $sub = substr($text, $pos, strlen($text)-$pos);

    if ($status)
        $newtext .= $sub;
    else
        $newtext .= convert_chars(wptexturize(wpautop($sub)));      //Apply both functions (faster)

    //To remove the tags
    $newtext = str_replace($tags[0], "", $newtext);
    $newtext = str_replace($tags[1], "", $newtext);

    return $newtext;
}

function newtexturize($text)
{
    return $text;   
}

function new_convert_chars($text)
{
    return $text;   
}

remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');
add_filter('the_content', 'newautop');

remove_filter('the_content', 'wptexturize');
add_filter('the_content', 'newtexturize');

remove_filter('the_content', 'convert_chars');
add_filter('the_content', 'new_convert_chars');
```

Comment: Ok i go to try , thank´s for help me , i put the result when i try , Thank´s !

Comment: No work me , continue insert these tags , i think the problem the div container use other class , i supose howewer can be the problem i don´t know but i put the function you put here and follow the instructions and continue the same problem , regards !